# How to access data from another datatemplate in wpf?

Tags: wpf, parameters, command, datatemplate

I have 2 Datatemplates.
One contain  a grid , second one contain a button.
I need to send command parameters of button as selected grid items.

How can i do this ?

```
<ObjectDataProvider x:Key="Datas" ObjectType="{x:Type ViewModel:UserControlViewModel}"></ObjectDataProvider>

<DataTemplate x:Key="SourceGrid">
<WPFToolKit:DataGrid x:Name="SourceDataGrid" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource Datas},Path=SourceGridData}" CanUserSortColumns="True" GridLinesVisibility="None" IsSynchronizedWithCurrentItem="True" SelectionUnit="FullRow"></WPFToolKit:DataGrid>
</DataTemplate>

<DataTemplate x:Key="AddRemoveDataTemplate">
<StackPanel>
<Button Name="Add" Content="Add">
<Button.Command>
<Binding Source="{StaticResource Datas}" Path="AddCommand"> 
</Binding>
</Button.Command>
<Binding ElementName="SourceDataGrid" Path="SelectedItem"></Binding>
</Button.CommandParameter>
</Button>
<StackPanel>
</DataTemplate>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to use a `Binding` with the `RelativeSource` property set to the `FindAncestor` mode and looking for a `DataGrid` object. However, I am not sure whether it will work in your scenario because I do not know how these `DataTemplate`s are related to each other. Is the second `DataTemplate` used for the items in the `DataGrid`?!

Somehow, your design feels strange to me. Are you sure that you need `DataTemplate`s in both cases? What exactly do you want to achieve?

Comment: I am having 3  datatemplates 
1- source grid.
2- add/remove buttons
3 - destination grid

I have one question - DataGrids's selected items is a dependency property. Can I assignn it to a view-model declared property ?

Comment: This is fine. But what does "source grid", "add/remove buttons", and "destination grid" *mean* and what do they *do*? You know, you need to provide some more details, otherwise we won't be able to help you. Regarding `SelectedItems`: It is *not* a dependency property. Only `SelectedItem` (singular!) is a dependency property that you can use for data binding. However, you can use the Event-to-Command pattern or an attached property to enable data binding to the `SelectedItems` property. [Laurent Bugnion recently blogged about the former approach.](http://tinyurl.com/38kpof9)

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at this article. Maybe it'll help you:

http://www.dev102.com/2008/08/07/how-to-access-a-wpf-control-which-is-located-in-a-datatemplate/

Comment: I'm not looking for a code-behind solution.
There is some issue in referring the "SourceDataGrid" in the following way...thats what i'm looking for
<Binding ElementName="SourceDataGrid" path="SelectedItem"></Binding>