# Two-way Databinding a WP7 Toolkit Multiselect ListPicker SelectedItems Property to a ViewModel

Tags: windows-phone-7.1, silverlight-toolkit, windows-phone-7

I have a WP7 Toolkit ListPicker that is set to MultiSelect mode and I need to databind the SelectedItems property to a collection on the ViewModel. The ListPicker SelectedItems property is readonly.

```
<toolkit:ListPicker x:Name="ItemTypePicker" 
ItemsSource="{Binding ItemTypes}" 
SelectionMode="Multiple" />
```

Is there anyway to databind the SelectedItems property to a property on the ViewModel?

thanks
Michael

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2911996/how-do-i-bind-selecteditem-property-of-wpftoolkit-datagrid-to-my-viewmodel-prope this seems to be similar to what you need.

Answer (score 0):

Will you be requiring to set the SelectedItems or just to read from them?

If read is all you need, I think the best solution is to just use the SelectionChanged event, as you can see in [this post](http://geekswithblogs.net/lbugnion/archive/2010/05/19/handling-datagrid.selecteditems-in-an-mvvm-friendly-manner.aspx) from Laurent Bugnion

Answer (score 0):

Try: ItemsSource="{Binding ItemTypes, Mode=TwoWay}"